# Change Tkinter Frame Title

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, title

I am trying to figure out how to change the title of a Tkinter Frame. Below is simplified code that mimics the portion of my program where I am trying to change the title:

```
from Tkinter import *

class start_window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        Frame.pack(self)
        Label(self, text = 'Test', width=30).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_window().mainloop()
```

With this sample code the Frame has the standard "tk" title but I would like to change it to something like "My Database". I've tried everything I can think of with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in  __init__() add self.master.title('My Title')

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("My Database")
    root.geometry("500x400")
    app = start_window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be explicitly creating the main window by creating an instance of `Tk`. When you do, you can use the reference to this window to change the title.

I also recommend *not* using a global import. Instead, import tkinter by name,and prefix your tkinter commands with the module name. I use the name `tk` to cut down on typing:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class start_window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame.pack(self)
        tk.Label(self, text = 'Test', width=30).pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("This is my title")
    start_window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Finally, to make your code easier to read I suggest giving your class name an uppercase first letter to be consistent with almost all python programmers everywhere:

```
class StartWindow(...):
```

By using the same conventions as everyone else, it makes it easier for us to understand your code.

For more information about naming conventions used by the tkinter community, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work for me. After making the suggested modifications I end up with two widget windows, one that looks like my original widget and a second that is blank but has the desired title. However the next answer did solve my issue. Thanks I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: You will end up with two windows if you create some widgets before you call `tk.Tk()`. You should explicitly create the root window before you create any other widgets.

Answer (score 2):

I generally start my tkinter apps with

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import Tkinter as tk

root = Tk() 

root.title('The name of my app')

root.minsize(300,300)
root.geometry("800x800")

root.mainloop()
```